# Plot of a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying yesterday to plot the function `f(x)=1/x , 1<=x<=2 and f(x)=x , x<=0`.
I was using the pgf plot, but the code was not working and  since it was getting on my nerves I just deleted it.

Thus I don't know to plot this.It has some jump discontinuities and perhaps I need to add some packages to work. Anyway, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-1.7066666666666666,0.0) -- (2.56888888888889,0.0);
\foreach \x in {-1.5,-1.0,-0.5,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]{\footnotesize  $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0.0,-1.3644444444444437) -- (0.0,1.924444444444442);
\foreach \y in {-1.0,-0.5,0.5,1.0,1.5}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize  $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-1.7066666666666666,-1.3644444444444437) rectangle (2.56888888888889,1.924444444444442);
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=1.0000037066666696:1.9999985707336516] plot(\x,{\Alpha\nu[1.0*≤*(\x)*≤*2.0,1.0/x]});
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-1.7066666666666666:-1.7066666650448171E-6] plot(\x,{\Alpha\nu[x*≤*0.0,x]});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (-2.1511111111111108,-2.1733333333333316) node {$g$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That is the code, I don't remember the specific commands I inserted in plots...
And for some reasons I can't seem to get the code properly here... I must have made some mistakes.. If someone could correct it.. I would be grateful.

Comment: Show your not working code.

Answer (score 1):

Run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(3,2.5)
\psaxes[Dx=0.5,Dy=0.5]{->}(0,0)(-1.75,-1.25)(2.5,2)
\psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic]{1}{2}{1/x}
\psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic]{-1}{0}{x}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not compile... it does not identify that \psaxes... although I added the package of the preamble

Comment: "It does not compile" is not a useful error description ... . I have no problem ...

Answer (score 1):

With `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines*=middle,
        no markers,
        ymin=-2, ymax=2,
        enlargelimits={abs=1},
        axis line style={latex-latex},
        xtick={-2,-1,1,2},
        ytick={-2,-1,1,2}
        ]
        \addplot+ [thick, samples=50, smooth,domain=1:2,blue] {1/x};
        \addplot+ [thick, samples=50, smooth,domain=-2:0,olive] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun with `tikz`. Have a look at the `pgfmanual` and the tutorials (the first chapters). It contains every information you need.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  % axes
  \draw [<->] (0,-2.5) -- ++(0,5);
  \draw [<->] (-2.5,0) -- ++(5,0);
  \foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2} {
   \draw (\x,.125) -- ++(0,-.25) node [below] {\scriptsize \x};
   \draw (.125,\x) -- ++(-.25,0) node [left] {\scriptsize \x};
  }
  % plots
  \draw [red, domain=1:2] plot ({\x}, {1/\x});
  \draw [blue, domain=-2:0] plot ({\x}, {\x});
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]